# How to use RAM for OS Storage?

Tags: memory, operating-systems

I recently heard from my friend that you can modify the RAM so that it can be used to boot the OS and it would work even faster than SSDs. I don't expect to run Windows on it but maybe some Linux might do the work. So, is there a way to use RAM as OS Storage?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive

Comment: If some OS isn't booted first, there is nothing in ram.